# How to get most likely value with confidence interval or expected value from a set of observations

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

lets say I have a set of values (R-code below for creating a vector)

```
x <- c(5.0, 4.8, 4.3, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 4.6, 4.5, 4.2, 4.1, 4.6, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 4.2, 4.4, 4.8, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.3, 4.1)
```

I want to calculate most likely value with a range.
or in other words, an expected value for x.

I think in normally distributed data it would be mean and confidence interval.
I don't want to assume that its normally distributed also does not look like one in the density plot.
[image]

Comment: Is that supposed to be some kind of time series (or other sequential data)? // If not, how would you expect the answer to change if you shuffled the values or went backwards?

Comment: No further assumptions about the data generating process? Linear or recycling cyclically?  You will need to make some assumptions for a good answer.

Comment: @Dave, its not sequential or time series. the answer should not change by shuffling the values. just by adding more observations it should change

Comment: The data is observations from an experiment, I do not want to assume that its normally distributed (in which case the answer would be mode with confidence intervals?)

Comment: There is a strong signal in your data that the values are decreasing as the sequence goes on: `y <- x; x <- seq(1, length(y), 1); L <- lm(y ~ x); summary(L)`. This might indicate something, particularly something that might help you get a better estimate of the next value via regression or time series forecasting.

Comment: This question is confusing in that it somehow puts a "mode" and a "confidence interval" on an equal or comparable footing--but those two concepts have virtually no connection.  Moreover, your question admits several conflicting interpretations.  For instance, do you wish to obtain a confidence interval for a mode?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have deleted my answer until the question can be clarified, in hopes of keeping someone from reading my answer while thinking I am answering a different question than I thought I was answering.

Comment: @whuber, I think I am lacking the skills to ask the right question. But another attempt, Given a set of observation x, I am looking for an expected value of x with some buffer. I suspect I am still not using the right words but can you guide me to the answer ?

Comment: @Dave I think I do not want to use the sequence, the values of x are not necessarily in a particular sequence, just a sample of observations. I don't have any other attribute to do regression and time series forecasting. I am just looking for an expected value. e.g. in a normal distribution, it will be mean+/- sd with 95% confidence

Comment: "Expected value of x with some buffer" sounds like a *confidence interval for the mean.*  In your case, it wouldn't matter that the data don't look quite normally distributed: the standard Normal confidence interval will do just fine.

Comment: Bootstrappling the mode of R's default KDE works better than I guessed it would.

Comment: @BruceET I remember trying that once and finding that my confidence intervals *widened* as I increased my sample size. (Perhaps that means I had a bug in my code, but I couldn’t find it.)

Comment: @Dave. If you're using a large sample from a population with a single distinct mode, I think the KDE will work well. Try Laplace. // However, I have to say I haven't had a lot of experience making CIs for population modes.

Comment: @Dave. I just tried samples of size 25,70, and 1000 from $\mathsf{Norm}(50,7).$ Got 95% CIs $(46.4, 52.1), (48.3, 51.4), (49.6, 50.4),$ pretty much as expected. Howerver, modes from R default KDEs were $41.42, 50.81, 47.89$ and surprisingly narrow bootstrap CIs for mode: $(51.40,51.44), (50.79, 50.83), (47.87,47.92),$ Now "Looking for **my** bug, can't find it." Pondering whether there's some obvious reason I'm stupidly missing that modes shouldn't be bootstrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key comment above is @Bernhard's statement that you may need to
make additional assumptions for a good answer. One
reasonable assumption is that the data are normal.

Descriptive statistics (fron R) are as follows:

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   4.00    4.15    4.30    4.37    4.60    5.00 
table(x)
x
  4 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.8   5 
  3   3   4   3   2   1   3   3   1
```

So that the sample mean median and mode are all around
4.2-4.4.

As you have noticed, a kernel density estimator has its
maximum $(4.195),$ near this interval.

```
cutp = seq(3.85,5.15, by=.1)
hist(x, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2")
 lines(density(x), lwd=3, col="orange")
```

[image]

In R a density estimator consists of 512 $(x,y)$ pairs, which
can be retrieved as follows:

```
xx = density(x)$x
yy = density(x)$y
mean(xx[yy==max(yy)])
[1] 4.194887
```

With such a small sample, it is futile to try to determine
whether the population is normal. However, an *assumption*
that data are normal is not foolish. According to the
Shapiro-Wilk test, your data are consistent with sampling from a normal population.

```
shapiro.test(x)$p.val
[1] 0.08378559
```

Also a normal Q-Q plot is not far from linear.

```
qqnorm(x)
qqline(x, col="blue")
```

[image]

For a normal distribution, the mean, median, and mode
are the same, so it seems reasonable to find a 95% CI
for the population mode using the 95% CI
$(4.24, 4.50)$ for the mean, from a t test.

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 4.242862 4.496269
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

**Addendum:** Here is a method that makes as few assumptions as possible. Take $B = 2000$ re-samples from the
sample `x` of size $n = 23$ with replacement and
use the method above with the density estimator
to see the variety of the resulting 2000 modes.
Then use a bias-corrected quantile method to
make a 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI for the
population mode.

*Reprise the given sample:*

```
x
 [1] 5.0 4.8 4.3 4.4 4.6 4.8 4.6 4.5 4.2 4.1 4.6 4.2
[13] 4.2 4.3 4.2 4.4 4.8 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.1 4.3 4.1
xx = density(x)$x
yy = density(x)$y
mode.obs = mean(xx[yy==max(yy)])
mode.obs
[1] 4.194887
```

*Make a 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI* $(4.17, 4.22).$

```
set.seed(526)
B = 2000;  d.re = numeric(B)
for (i in 1:B) {
 x.re = sample(x, n, rep=T)
 xr = density(x.re)$x
 yr = density(x.re)$y
 d.re[i] = mean(xr[yr=-max(yr)])-mode.obs
}
UL = quantile(d, c(.975,.025))
mode.obs - UL
   97.5%     2.5% 
4.171117 4.217429
```

*Show four of the 2000 re-samples with KDEs for each.*
(R code for figure not shown.)

[image]

*Note:* Nothing here suggests that other interesting ideas in Comments
are not useful.